# Manifest merger failed, While no error in merged manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, merged-manifest

My android Studio is displaying titled error, but while i am checking out my merged manifest, No error there. Below are SS of my merged manifest and manifest files. ***targetSdkVersion 34***

**Merged Manifest**

[image]

**Manifest**

[image]

Comment: Your targetApi is 31 while your targetSdkVersion is 34, see if it helps to unify these 2 values. (see your build.gradle file). Also, double check that the value of @string/app_name is valid.

Comment: @OmarHezi, Thanks for replying, I have changes target api 34 and app name is also valid, but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when i update **junit dependencies**, Merge manifest error wash out.

**Here is old versions :**

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

**Updated Versions are here :**

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```